# JSON to XML : How to avoid the special character encoding # to _x0023_?

Tags: c#, json, xml

```cs
var data = "{\"#access_token\":\"Vishnu\"}";
XmlDocument doc = (XmlDocument)Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(data.ToString(), "root", false, false);
var output = doc.InnerXml.ToString();

// Expected output: <root><#access_token>Vishnu</#access_token></root>
// Actual output: <root><_x0023_access_token>Vishnu</_x0023_access_token></root>

public static XmlDocument DeserializeXmlNode(
    string value,
    string deserializeRootElementName,
    bool writeArrayAttribute,
    bool encodeSpecialCharacters  // both true and false gives same result.
)
```

Please give a method to get the `#` as it is XML.

Comment: `#` isn't a valid [NameStartChar](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#NT-NameStartChar). You therefore shouldn't expect any well designed XML tooling to produce one. Nor, to be fair, should something claiming to accept XML want you to generate such an item.

Comment: You are using HTML so you have to follow HTML special character and not XML.  Why does the tagname have the # character?

Comment: #access_token is a key which is received as part of Oauth2.0 flow and we must keep it

Comment: Maybe so,  but that doesn't mean that you can violate the rules of XML that says that an element name cannot start with a `#`. It's certainly *not* a requirement of `Oauth2.0` that you try and store your auth token in XML, let alone dictates the name of the XML element to be an invalid one.

Comment: But I could not get it correct for "access#_token". i.e # is not the NameStartChar.

Comment: Is # a NameChar?

Comment: Got it. Thank you.

According to the XML specification, # is not a valid character in an XML name, so it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Something that claims to convert JSON to XML can hopefully be relied upon to produce well-formed XML; it seems you want it to produce XML containing invalid characters in element names, which would not be useful to anyone.

Different JSON-to-XML converters have different ways of dealing with this problem, but at least if it's well formed XML you can then write an XSLT transformation to convert it to the XML you would like to see.

(If you want even more control over how the transformation is done, do the whole thing within an XSLT 3.0 stylesheet.)